# Google APIs Console: Error Creating OAuth 2.0 Client ID not sufficient permissions

Tags: oauth, google-oauth, google-api-console

I am trying to use the Google APIs Console to create an OAuth 2.0 for Login and create Client ID as a Web application. I've already created several Client ID's , but after ~60 entries i cannot create a Client ID any more. I get the following error "you do not have sufficient permissions to view this page".I tried to delete an existing ID and recreate it and it worked fine .

Is there a limit at the number of the Client IDs i can create ?

Comment: Why would you want more then one Client id?   And why on earth would you ever need 60+ of them.

Comment: Cause i need to create ID for every one of the domains of the platform i work on. (ie example.de, example.fr  etc)

Comment: Why not use the same one?

Comment: I had the impression that Google Api worked similarly to Facebook one about the ID. In facebook API, for 20 different domains, i had to create 20 different Apps with their IDs . Is it possible for Google API to be used with only one ID?

Comment: Which Google API are you trying to access?    I don't know if there being any limit to the number of sites you can use it from.